# Format-Table returning blank column

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm having trouble only displaying the `Time` column for a command.

```
Get-EventLog -log Security | where {$_.EventID -eq 4800 -or $_.EventID -eq 4801}
```

returns:

```
   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message                                                                                                                  
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------                                                                                                                  
  167513 Mar 14 10:31  SuccessA... Microsoft-Windows...         4801 The workstation was unlocked....                                                                                         
  167506 Mar 14 10:14  SuccessA... Microsoft-Windows...         4800 The workstation was locked....                                                                                           
  167499 Mar 14 10:08  SuccessA... Microsoft-Windows...         4801 The workstation was unlocked....
```

However if I *only* want to see the `Time` column I get nothing:

> Get-EventLog -log Security | where {$*.EventID -eq 4800 -or $*.EventID
>   -eq 4801} | Format-Table Time

```
Time                                                                                                                                                                                          
----
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's blank because there are no such thing as a `Time` property. It's an alias used in the default view of `Get-EventLog`.

```
PS > Get-EventLog -LogName System | gm


   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry#System/EventLog/2147489661

Name                      MemberType     Definition
----                      ----------     ----------  
....                                    
TimeGenerated             Property       datetime TimeGenerated {get;}
TimeWritten               Property       datetime TimeWritten {get;}
UserName                  Property       string UserName {get;}
EventID                   ScriptProperty System.Object EventID {get=$this.get_EventID() -band 0x...
```

Use `Format-Table TimeGenerated` to get the time when the event happend, and `TimeWritten` to get the time it was saved to the log.

The column `Time` in the default view is `TimeGenerated` formated like `{0:MMM} {0:dd} {0:HH}:{0:mm}`. You can see this in one of the format files in Powershell. For this case, it's in "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml" :

```
.....
<ViewSelectedBy>
    <TypeName>System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry</TypeName>
</ViewSelectedBy>
.....
<TableColumnHeader>
    <Label>Time</Label>
    <Width>13</Width>
</TableColumnHeader>
.....
<TableColumnItem>
    <PropertyName>TimeGenerated</PropertyName>
    <FormatString>{0:MMM} {0:dd} {0:HH}:{0:mm}</FormatString>
</TableColumnItem>
.....
```